# How do I prove the following equality (Matrix)?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$(I+P^{T}\Sigma^{-1}P)^{-1}P^T\Sigma^{-1}=P^T(\Sigma+PP^T)^{-1}$$

I have tried to apply the matrix inversion lemma on $(I+P^TΣ^{−1}P)^{−1}$ and recovered

$$(I+P^{T}\Sigma^{-1}P)^{-1}P^T\Sigma^{-1}=[I-P^T(\Sigma+PP^T)^{-1}P]P^T\Sigma^{-1}$$

$P$ is a d by n matrix, $\Sigma$ is a d by d matrix

But still, I am stuck. I have verified the equality numerically by assigning a random matrix to $P$ and a random symmetric matrix to $\Sigma$

Comment: Can you confirm the dimensions of your variables? As far as I can see, your initial left hand side has the term $I \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} + (p^T \Sigma^{-1} p) \in \mathbb{C}$. These two elements cannot be "added."

Comment: sorry $p$ is not a vector, it is also a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove:
$$(I+P^{T}\Sigma^{-1}P)^{-1}P^T\Sigma^{-1}=P^T(\Sigma+PP^T)^{-1}$$

As you have done, use the matrix inversion lemma on $(I+P^TΣ^{−1}P)^{−1}$, and expand out the terms:

$$\begin{aligned}
(I+P^{T}\Sigma^{-1}P)^{-1}P^T\Sigma^{-1} &= [I-P^T(\Sigma+PP^T)^{-1}P]P^T\Sigma^{-1}\\
&= P^{T} \Sigma^{-1} - P^T (\Sigma+PP^T)^{-1}PP^T \Sigma^{-1}
\end{aligned}$$

Now the key step is to add and subtract a term in order to cancel out this complicated inverse. So by adding and subtracting $P^T(\Sigma + PP^T)^{-1}\Sigma\Sigma^{-1}$ to this RHS we get:

$$\begin{aligned}
&= P^{T} \Sigma^{-1} - P^T (\Sigma+PP^T)^{-1}(\Sigma+PP^T) \Sigma^{-1} + P^T(\Sigma + PP^T)^{-1}\Sigma\Sigma^{-1}\\
&= P^T\Sigma^{-1} - P^T \Sigma^{-1} + P^T (\Sigma+PP^T)^{-1}\\
&= P^T (\Sigma+PP^T)^{-1}
\end{aligned}$$